Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: - error
Im using macOs for the 1st time and now I have a problem with working on c++ in VScode. After start of program I always so this error. Please, help anyone with this. Tnx!
code
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int num1 = 5;
    int num2 = 10;

    int sum = num1 + num2;
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

output
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_main", referenced from: <initial-undefines> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
tnx for help!
enter image description here

Make sure you save the code before running it, that solved my issue
